# плагин karma-coverage работает не так как ожидал

Tags: javascript, юнит-тесты, karma

Начну с кода:

```
// karma.config.js
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
        browsers: ['Chrome'],

        frameworks: ['jasmine'],

        files: [
            './src/**/*.js',
            './tests/**/*spec.js'
        ],

        reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],

        preprocessors: {
            'src/**/*.js': ['coverage']
        },

        coverageReporter: {
            type : 'html',
            dir : 'coverage/'
        }
    });
};
```

Мой проект из 3 файлов и одного теста:

```
// ./src/functions.js
function sum (a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

function sub (a, b) {
    return a - b;
}

function mul (a, b) {
    return a * b;
}

function div (a, b) {
    return a / b;
}

// ./src/formuls.js
function f1 (a, b, c) {
    return c - div(sum(a, b), sub(a, b));
}

function f2 (a, b, c) {
    return c + mul(a, b);
}

// ./src/index.js
/*var a = 10;
var b = 6;
var c = 3;

console.log(f1(a, b, c) + f2(a, b, c));
*/

// мои тесты

// ./tests/formuls.spec.js
describe("formuls unit tests", function () {

  it("f1", function () {
    expect(f1(2, 1, 3)).toBe(0);
  });

  it("f2", function () {
    expect(f2(2, 1, 3)).toBe(5);
  });

});
```

Т.е. тесты написаны только для модуля `formuls.js` а для модуля `functions.js` их нет. но! Если мы запустим тесты и откроем результат плагина *coverage*, то увидим, что проект покрыт тестами на 100%. Но это же не так.

Если я правильно понял, этот плагин смотрит какие функции были вызваны. т.е. по сути функции `sum`, `sub`, `mul`, `div` были вызваны. Но они были вызваны не для тестирования, а как (не знаю как правильно описать) "вторичные". т.е. функцию которую мы тестируем, вызывает другую функцию, на которую тоже надо написать тесты (но тестов нет).

И если посмотрите на файл `index.js`, то он закоменчен. Если его раскомментировать и вообще удалить все тесты, то получается что плагин `karma-coverage` опять выдаст `100%`. Потому что все функции были вызваны, но они то были вызваны не в виде тестов, а только потому что `index.js` дал старт, и по цепочке пошло все выполняться.

Что делать при такой ситуации?